# vector equation of a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How do I get the vector equation of the following line, I can't figure it out:

$y = 0$, $x \in [0,20]$.

$y = x - 20$, $x > 20$.

So the equation passes through all the points $(18,0), (19,0), (25,5)$ for example.

Where $y \ge 0$ all times.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "vector equation"?

Comment: The given equation is not of a line. It is a non-linear function y = max(0, x-20)

Comment: All lines are non-linear functions (affines) but I'm trying to find its vector equation as written above

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Heaviside function:

$$
\Theta(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
0, & x < 0 \\
1, & x \geq 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

then

$$
\boldsymbol{r}(t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x(t) \\
y(t)
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
t \\
(t-20)\Theta(t-20)
\end{pmatrix}, t \geq 0
$$